# Sidekiq Pro calling brpoplpush throwing ArgumentError "wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 2)"

Tags: ruby, redis, sidekiq

This error makes no sense because [`brpoplpush` in Ruby Redis 5.0.5](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/1f09bfa27dde5b8d872e9bde53b69d37dba1d7a5/lib/redis/commands/lists.rb#L181) *expects* three arguments, and  Sidekiq Pro 5.5.2 calls `brpoplpush` *with* three arguments on line 355 of lib/sidekiq/pro/super_fetch.rb:

```
      result = conn.brpoplpush(queue, working_queue, config[:fetch_timeout] || 1)
```

Here is the error in Sentry:

[image]

From our Gemfile.lock:

```
sidekiq-pro (5.5.2)
  sidekiq (>= 6.5.0)

redis (5.0.5)
  redis-client (>= 0.9.0)
```

Comment: It looks like you upgraded the Redis gem to a new major version without upgrading Sidekiq Pro.

Comment: I'll try again. I did try to upgrade initially, and a higher version of Sidekiq Pro (or maybe it was Sidekiq) prevented us from upgrading the Redis Gem (now installed via the redis_clustering gem), which we needed to upgrade quickly to handle an infrastructure change (to MemoryDB) for some uses of Redis independent of Sidekiq. But maybe I misunderstood or missed some combination of gems that would have worked for all use cases.

Comment: @MikePerham Sidekiq Pro won't let us upgrade without upgrading Sidekiq, but the upgraded version of Sidekiq is incompatible with the version of the redis gem required by the redis-clustering gem. We need the redis-clustering gem to operate our other Redis use cases with MemoryDB on AWS.

We've left Sidekiq operating on Elasticache Redis, so I think we'll be fine once we can update Sidekiq Pro to 7 and take advantage of redis-client's independence from the redis gem.

Comment: Discovered that the redis gem used to support clustering, so we abandoned the redis-clustering gem for redis 4.8, and all our Redis use cases appear to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature on that method includes a named argument `timeout` which defaults to 0. Ruby will accept a hash at end of the list of arguments, but not an Integer or similar.

I suspect `config[:fetch_timeout]` is nil, therefore the value of `1` is being passed, thus the error message.

Maybe see where `config[:fetch_timeout]` is being set and make sure it contains a hash value like `{ timeout: 1 }`.

If you want to get your head around why you get that particular error message, consider this method:

```
def foo(a, test: 1)
  puts test
end
```

Calling `foo(1, 1)` will trigger a `(wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1))` error, whereas `foo(1, test: 2)` will work.

Comment: Ah. They changed it to a named argument :facepalm:. I should have seen that. The number of arguments error is really confusing, rather than it saying something like "named argument expected", since I was looking at three arguments. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the issue you're seeing is a gem incompatibility.

If you upgrade to sidekiq 6.5.8, the redis version will be constrained automatically:

```
     sidekiq (6.5.8)
      connection_pool (>= 2.2.5, < 3)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      redis (>= 4.5.0, < 5)
```